# How to multiplex multiple blocking Python generators into one?

Tags: python, generator, python-2.7

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
def g_user():
    while True:
        yield read_user_input()

def g_socket():
    while True:
        yield read_socket_input()

def g_combined(gu, gs):
    # should read user or socket input, whichever is available

    while True:
        sel = select(gu, gs)
        if sel.contains(gu):
            yield gu.next()
        if sel.contains(gs):
            yield gs.next()

gc = g_combined ( g_user(), g_socket() )
```

How to implement this in easiest way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you might need to use an object more complex than just a generator, since besides just implementing `__next__()`, you'll need some kind of `is_ready()` method.

Comment: How to make this more complex object? Why it is not in standard library? (expected to see such thing in itertools, like `itertools.multiplex`)

Comment: Its probably not in itertools for the reason explained by your reference to genmulti. It requires threading to be accomplished since the generators don't really have a polling mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look's like someone already implemented this: http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/genmulti.py

Mirrored here:

```
import Queue, threading
def gen_multiplex(genlist):
    item_q = Queue.Queue()
    def run_one(source):
        for item in source: item_q.put(item)

    def run_all():
        thrlist = []
        for source in genlist:
            t = threading.Thread(target=run_one,args=(source,))
            t.start()
            thrlist.append(t)
        for t in thrlist: t.join()
        item_q.put(StopIteration)

    threading.Thread(target=run_all).start()
    while True:
        item = item_q.get()
        if item is StopIteration: return
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `select.select()` work properly, you'll need to expose a `fileno()` method on your generators that returns the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: "select" is just for pseudocode, to show what exactly I want.

Answer (score -2):

itertools module from standard library contains nice functions. In this specific case cycle function is good.

cycle  help says:

> cycle(iterable) --> cycle object
>
> Return elements from the iterable until it is exhausted. Then
>   repeat the sequence indefinitely.

Using cycle in your solution:

```
import itertools

def g_user():
    while True:
        yield read_user_input()

def g_socket():
    while True:
        yield read_socket_input()


def g_combine(*generators):
    for generator in itertools.cycle(generators):
        yield generator.next()


g_combined =  g_combine(g_user(), g_socket())
```

Considerations about this code:

1. g_combine ends with first generator that raise StopIteration
2. g_combine accepts N generators
3. How catch exceptions correctly? Think about.

Comment: No, it should not just interleave them like in "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" -> "ABCABCABC". The order in which input generators becomes readable is not predictable. It should not wait for g_user when g_socket is readable.